# Creating ArcGIS Raster Catalog with date/time fields from directory of NITF images?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, timeslider

I have a directory of NITF files, each with the idatim (timestamp) field set.  In the ArcMap properties, it shows up as "acquisition date" in the Key-Metadata table.  I would like to be able to create a raster catalog, mosaic, or something which will enable me to enable time support in ArcMap so I can create a time-lapse video.  The date field should be using this acquisition date.

I am getting familiar with ArcPy if that is a recommended solution. I have read through the ArcGIS documentation on using the time slider, how time is represented in datasets, and how to enable time on different products.  The key issue I am detecting is that when loading NITF rasters into a geodatabase, they do not set the key-metadata field as the date_time attribute.  I imagine there is a clever way of doing this, however I have not found it yet.  If this is not possible, what part of the NITF raster should provide the time.  I can update the NITF metadata myself if needed.

#### Some research

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005z00000004000000
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005z0000000p000000
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005z0000000q000000

Comment: This solution: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/115833/get-value-from-metadata-in-python-script-for-attribute may be useful.  It involves creating a temporary xml to read the metadata into your script.  Then you have it as a variable which you can use wherever you need.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by @jbalk:

> This solution:
>   [Getting value from Metadata in Python Script for attribute?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/115833/get-value-from-metadata-in-python-script-for-attribute)
>   may be useful.  It involves creating a temporary xml to read the
>   metadata into your script.  Then you have it as a variable which you
>   can use wherever you need.